# node-soap service that uses database (dependency issues)

Tags: node.js, database, web-services, service, node-soap

First of all, this is one of my first projects in Node.js so I'm very new to it.

I have a project I want to make that is a SOAP (I know, SOAP... backwards compatibility, huh?) interface that connects to an Oracle database.

So I have a WSDL describing what these functions look like (validation for addresses and stuff) and I have a connection to the database.

Now when using the SOAP npm module, you need to create a server and listen using a service that allows you to respond to requests. I have a separate file that contains my SOAP service but this service should do queries on the database to get its results.

How would I go about sort of 'injecting' my database service into my SOAP service so that whenever a SOAP call is done, it orchestrates this to the correct method in my database service?

This is what my code looks like:

**databaseconnection.js**

```
var oracledb = require('oracledb');
var dbConfig = require('../../config/development');

var setup = exports.setup = (callback) => {
    oracledb.createPool (
        {
            user          : dbConfig.user,
            password      : dbConfig.password,
            connectString : dbConfig.connectString
        },
        function(err, pool)
        {
            if (err) { console.error(err.message); return; }
            pool.getConnection (
                function(err, connection)
                {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err.message);
                        return callback(null);
                    }
                    return callback(connection);
                }
            );
        }
    );
};
```

**databaseservice.js**

```
var DatabaseService = function (connection) {
    this.database = connection;
};

function doSomething(callback) {
    if (!this.database) { console.log('Database not available.'); return; }
    this.database.execute('SELECT * FROM HELP', function(err, result) {
        callback(result);
    });
};

module.exports = {
    DatabaseService: DatabaseService,
    doSomething: doSomething
};
```

**soapservice.js**

```
var myService = {
    CVService: {
        CVServicePort: {
            countryvalidation: function (args, cb, soapHeader) {
                console.log('Validating Country');
                cb({
                    name: args
                });
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**server.js**

```
app.use(bodyParser.raw({type: function(){return true;}, limit: '5mb'}));
app.listen(8001, function(){
databaseconnection.setup((callback) => {
    var temp = databaseservice.DatabaseService(callback);
    soapservice.Init(temp);
    var server = soap.listen(app, '/soapapi/*', soapservice.myService, xml);

    databaseservice.doSomething((result) => {
    console.log(result.rows.length, ' results.');
    });
});
console.log('Server started');
});
```

How would I go about adding the databaseservice.doSomething() to the countryvalidation soap method instead of 'name: args'?

Also: I feel like the structure of my code is very, very messy. I tried finding some good examples on how to structure the code online but as for services and database connections + combining them, I didn't find much. Any comments on this structure are very welcome. I'm here to learn, after all.

Thank you

Dieter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I see that looks a little off is the databaseconnection.js. It should be creating the pool, but that's it. Generally speaking, a connection should be obtained from the pool when a request comes in and release when you're done using it to service that request.

Have a look at this post: https://jsao.io/2015/02/real-time-data-with-node-js-socket-io-and-oracle-database/ There are some sample apps you could have a look at that might help. Between the two demos, the "employees-cqn-demo" app is better organized.

Keep in mind that the post is a little dated now, we've made enhancements to the driver that make it easier to use now. It's on my list to do a post on how to build a RESTful API with Node.js and Oracle Database but I haven't had a chance to do it yet.

Comment: Thanks. I checked out the link and I managed to get the same type of structure working. I should be able to figure out the rest myself. Thanks so much.